# Not Receiving push notification in GCM

Tags: php, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am using Gcm service for Push notification in my app.

I am using this [Link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

After registering the client unable to receive push notification.

Help to receive Push from server.

Comment: can any one guide me properly

Comment: hi, I Have same problem.. Can you Share its solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check both the Sender id and the API id. After that you must check the android Manifest file like below

```
<permission
    android:name="your packagename.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="your package name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"        />
<receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="your package name" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service android:name="your package name.GCMIntentService" />
```

Comment: have you gotten device gcm id from gcm server ?

Comment: can you plz send code for sample application except the above link

Comment: I have also used same code . I had same problem but now working for me.

Comment: yes i got.. this is the id......APA91bFNIUaGxHU6bSYN2sinMEVahl5JBKUomSNBwtkGl5yIm0xmoK_RsTCljQH02rX7e5macYkHfmXKlahcOqsQRksomX-YmCfLHiypE1gO23KTYiZ3VdmMYg4jWU4cSBkJ3l7LL3ROlpY_9LazBjlN7Dba3MfO6CxtRHa9G5PSLzxg5w6l9iA

Comment: can plz suggest me an alternate solution

Comment: you just factory reset your phone and sync new gmail id It may help you

Comment: can u send me gcm server return if send message to above gcm id?

Comment: i do check by using emulator... how can i do factory reset in emulator